# Cannot access variable in innerclass : Android Studio

Tags: android

The goal from my projects is to assign which number that represents checkbox that checked into the empty array.

```
int [] mChecked = new int []{};
```

I tried to make a loop which checkbox number is clicked to and assign mCheked array to new value the number corresponds to the checkbox number, when I tried it failed to access variable in inner class. In android studio you must create new variable `final int FinalI = i;` to track the code, but if its final you cannot reassign the value.

This is the part of code that error.

```
 for(int i=0 ; i < arrayCheck.length ; i++)
    {

        arrayCheck[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

               mChecked[i] = i+1;

            }
        });
    }
```

especially on this line

```
mChecked[i] = i+1;
```

[image of error part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFNYl.jpg)

This is the full code

```
  package com.okssaami.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6, G7, G8, G9, G10, G11, G12, G13, G14, G15,
            G16, G17, G18, G19, G20, G21, G22, G23, G24, G25, G26, G27, G28, G29, G30,
            G31, G32, G33, G34;
    Button Submit;

    int [] mChecked = new int []{};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int [] ids = new int [] {
                R.id.G1,
                R.id.G2,
                R.id.G3,
                R.id.G4,
                R.id.G5,
                R.id.G6,
                R.id.G7,
                R.id.G8,
                R.id.G9,
                R.id.G10,
                R.id.G11,
                R.id.G12,
                R.id.G13,
                R.id.G14,
                R.id.G15,
                R.id.G16,
                R.id.G17,
                R.id.G18,
                R.id.G19,
                R.id.G20,
                R.id.G21,
                R.id.G22,
                R.id.G23,
                R.id.G24,
                R.id.G25,
                R.id.G26,
                R.id.G27,
                R.id.G28,
                R.id.G29,
                R.id.G30,
                R.id.G31,
                R.id.G32,
                R.id.G33,
                R.id.G34
        };

        final CheckBox [] arrayCheck = new CheckBox[ids.length];

        for(int i=0 ; i < arrayCheck.length ; i++)
        {
            arrayCheck[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(ids[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0 ; i < arrayCheck.length ; i++)
        {

            arrayCheck[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                   mChecked[i] = i+1;

                }
            });
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of your variable `i` being declared on the stack and then you try to use it after the stack is gone in an inner class (the compiler identifies that and tells you to use a final variable so it can use it inside the inner class). To understand exactly what you are doing wrong, you can have a look at this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inner-class-java/).

**Try this:**

```
for(int i=0 ; i < arrayCheck.length ; i++)
{
    final int value = i;
    arrayCheck[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

           mChecked[value] = value+1;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how you can add 1 to `value` variable as it is final?

Comment: I am not changing value at all. There is a "new" value for each iteration of the loop. It is saved in the inner class and used to access the array and set it to `value + 1`

Comment: Got it. You are not assigning value, you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you can't access a variable of a class, from its inner class if it is not final

> Local classes can most definitely reference instance variables. The reason they cannot reference non final local variables is because the local class instance can remain in memory after the method returns. When the method returns the local variables go out of scope, so a copy of them is needed. If the variables weren’t final then the copy of the variable in the method could change, while the copy in the local class didn’t, so they’d be out of synch.

See [this article](https://tech-read.com/2008/06/19/why-inner-class-can-access-only-final-variable/) for detailed explanation why is that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
 for(int i=0 ; i < arrayCheck.length ; i++)
    {
        arrayCheck[i].setTag(i);
        arrayCheck[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              int position= Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
              mChecked[position] = position+1;

            }
        });
    }
```

but it will add value to `mChecked` on checked and unchecked of checkbox.